# Switching between Spark YARN Client and Cluster mode when using Typesafe config

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, typesafe-config

Been struggling with an issue on handling multiple config files with Spark YARN and switching between cluster and client mode.

In my application, I need to load two config files:

1. An application config
2. An environment config

**My current setup:**

***example-application.conf***:

```
include required(file("env.conf"))

app {
  source
    {
      source-name: "some-source"
      source-type: "file"
      source-path: ${env.some-source-path}
    }
   ....
}
```

***env.conf:***

```
env {
  some-source-path: "/path/to/file"
}
```

Code:

```
// Spark submit that works:
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name ${APP_INSTANCE} \
    --files ${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/${ENV_NAME}/env.conf,${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/example-application.conf \
    --principal ${PRINCIPAL_NAME} --keytab ${KEYTAB_PATH} \
    --jars ${JARS} \
    --num-executors 10 \
    --executor-memory 4g \
    --executor-cores 4 \
    ${APP_JAR} "example-application.conf" "$@"

// How above file is loaded in code:
val appConfFile = new File(configFileName)   // configFileName = "example-application.conf"
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(appConfFile)
```

In cluster mode, the above setup works because the `--files` option of the spark-submit command will copy the files to all the nodes involved on cluster mode to the same location as the jars. Therefore, providing the name of the config file is good enough.

However, I am not sure how to get this setup to work such that I can easily swap my application from client to cluster mode. In client mode, the application fails because the ConfigFactory cannot find the `example-application.conf` to parse it. I can fix this by providing the full path for the application config but then the include function `include required(file("env.conf"))` will fail.

Any recommendations on how to set this up so that I can easily swap between cluster and client mode?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you executing spark-submit command using shell script ? & how are you switching between client & cluster mode .. do you have any variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass complete path of config file as part of spark-submit & handle the logic of extracting inside your spark code.

`spark.submit.deployMode=client` then take full path i.e `${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/example-application.conf`

`spark.submit.deployMode=cluster` then take only file name i.e `example-application.conf`

```
// Spark submit that works:
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name ${APP_INSTANCE} \
    --files ${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/${ENV_NAME}/env.conf,${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/example-application.conf \
    --principal ${PRINCIPAL_NAME} --keytab ${KEYTAB_PATH} \
    --jars ${JARS} \
    --num-executors 10 \
    --executor-memory 4g \
    --executor-cores 4 \
    ${APP_JAR} ${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/example-application.conf "$@"
```

```
// How above file is loaded in code:

val configFile = if(!spark.conf.get("spark.submit.deployMode").contains("client")) configFileName.split("/").last else configFileName

val appConfFile = new File(configFile)   // configFileName = "example-application.conf"
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(appConfFile)
```

Comment: ok, In above question he is wants to use config file when spark deploy-mode is client or cluster,  for that i have written this solution to handle config files both modes.  do you see any issue in this approach ?

Comment: Not the expert here, we used cluster mode always --> simplification approach here. But I quite like uber jars which was also the approach. No, I think u know what u r doing, just wanted to make sure not forgotten. Cool.

Comment: I actually tried the full path approach, however the problem is with the `env.conf` through the include operation ---> It will fail if I don't update the `include` to also point to the full path of the `env.conf`. I guess I can't get around this?